# Silent mode execution with java.exe

Tags: java, background-process

I would like to know if there is a way to execute the "java.exe" as a background process (silent mode execution)

Ex: java -cp . MyClass arg1

I want to run the above statement as  a background process , without opening command window

Comment: what do you mean with silent mode execution? suppress all console output?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Under Windows, use `javaw.exe` instead of `java.exe`. See [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) for link, relevant bit copied here:

> The `javaw` command is identical to `java`, except that with `javaw` there is no associated console window. Use `javaw` when you don't want a command prompt window to appear. The `javaw` launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some reason.

Comment: @paxdiablo would it keep running this way if log out from Windows ?

Comment: @kommradHomer, no idea, you'd have to try it. I doubt it myself since it's not running as a service.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
javaw -cp . MyClass arg1
```

(assuming you're on MS windows)

If you're looking at services rather then applications then have a look at 'service wrappers'