# running an R script in batch mode without the command prompt popping up

Tags: windows, r, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

I have a scheduled task (using `SCHTASKS`) to run every minute.

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 1 /TN READSCALE /TR "Rcmd BATCH --vanilla --slave q:\workspace\waga\readScale.R"
```

On each run command prompt window pops up. It's slightly irritating and perhaps a potential health hazard for people with epilepsy. In Java, one can use `javaw.exe` ([see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902656/silent-mode-execution-with-java-exe)) that doesn't pop up a command prompt. Is there an equivalent for R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kudos to serverfault.com, where some people solved the problem using no external tools at least in two ways. [Here's the thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window).

First is to write a .vbs script. This requires some knowledge of this scripting language and may not be appropriate for everyone.

The second method is to run the task (as I'm doing) under SYSTEM (and not the currently logged in user).

Answer (score 2):

Ah, Windows... There is a tool called [hstart](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html) which may help here.

Comment: I just ran into this tool this morning. Great minds think alike? :) I will try it in the afternoon and accept this as the correct answer if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I found a better way (without external tools). See my answer below that should appear shortly.