# How to schedule R task using Windows Scheduler?

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using Windows 8.1 and would like to know how can I schedule a R task to run daily at certain timing.

I know this questions have been posted quite a few times here, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I know I need to create a .bat file, but I can't seems to get it working. I have tried:

`@echo off
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/bin/x64/R.exe" CMD BATCH
   --vanilla --slave "D:/Users/user/folder/myScript.R"`

`@echo off
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/bin/x64/R.exe" CMD BATCH "D:/Users/user/folder/myScript.R"`

I have also tried replacing R.exe with RScript.eve, and a few other random variations of it, but to no avail.

I am a complete newbie to using command line and such. Anyone can guide me through?

Comment: I suppose you've seen this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719869/running-an-r-script-in-batch-mode-without-the-command-prompt-popping-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

```
@echo off
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/bin/x64/R.exe" D:/Users/user/folder/myScript.R
```