# Spring Boot Application getting down when command prompt is closed

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have spring boot application as a service and i want to deploy it as jar.So i run this jar file in command prompt on windows.but when i close the command prompt ,service is also getting down.I want to run this boot service in Background and only shutdown when i want.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silent mode execution with java.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902656/silent-mode-execution-with-java-exe)

Comment: see http://www.tanukisoftware.com/en/index.php

Comment: Its jar file and i am running on windows with java -jar myapp.jar command..its not exe.

Comment: @ajaygoswami You don't have to enter the `.exe` extension on the command line to run a windows executable. Replace `java` by `javaw` this should solve your problem (see link in my other comment)